# Question on this sentence "some of the balls are red"

Tags: dative

*Rosetta stone* says it's

> einige der Bälle sind rote.

I don't understand why *die* goes to *der*. Does *einige* change it to dative case? I couldn't find anything online and *Rosetta stone* won't tell me

Comment: That's called plural. Not much to do with [tag:dative].

Comment: Why isnt it einige die bälle sind rot then?

Comment: _"Einige Bälle sind rot"_ seems to make more sense.

Comment: As it has not been explicitly mentioned and is tangential to the focus of the question: "rote" rather than "rot" is rather unidiomatic and would only fit in specific contexts. It would sound right if you already knew some of the balls that could possibly be there are red, and you are maybe specifically looking for red balls. In most other situations, you would just say "... sind rot."

Answer (score 8):

*der Bälle* is plural genitive case here.
(Dativ would be *den Bällen*)

This is not related to *einige*.

"some of the balls" is a linguistic construction called "nominal partitive" (as in 'something is part of a group'). In German, the partitive is expressed using the genitive case.